# (No Title) is appearing on new and edit list forms

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

At the top of the list new and edit forms it shows the title column.  If nothing is in the title it says "No Title".  How can I remove this from happening and why did it happen?

Comment: Cannot reproduce that. If a list item has no title, I see "List Name - " in the form header. If the item has a title I see "List Name - Title value". Is your site customized in any way?

Comment: No, it's not. I allowed management of content types, then clicked on Item in content types, clicked on title under columns and hid the title column.  Checked to see if it was hidden and for some reason it wasn't. Then did the above steps again but clicked on Item under Source then clicked Title under Column and hid that as well.  After that it started showing the title field contents next to the List Title on the top of the page, for both new and edit forms.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Even with the Title field hidden in the form, the title will show in the form header when the field has a value and will show as a blank after the "List Name - " when it's empty.

Comment: Let me make sure I understand what you are saying. You're saying that after you hide the title field, and when you edit a form, the title will show at the top of the page (above the actual columns)?  Is that normal?

Answer (score 1):

Create a Custom List. Make the title field optional. Create a new item, enter some text in the Title field and save.

Allow management of content types, edit the Item content type and make the title field hidden.

Create another item and save.

The first item, where the title field has content, will not appear in the form itself, but the value will be displayed in the header of the overlay form.

[image]

The second item, where the Title field has no value, will show with a blank space after the list name and dash:

[image]

This is the out-of-the-box behaviour. If you see something different, then chances are that something has been changed in your setup.

Comment: I'm the person who originally asked the question, however I can't "add comment" to your above answer. I have SharePoint 2007. So you're saying, OOTB, it always shows the Title Field value up top above the form?

Comment: Sigh. You might have mentioned the version a tad earlier. It ***does*** make a difference. In SP 2007 you will see the (no title) on the page if the title field is empty. Either design your list in a way that the title field is populated (you can rename it to be called something else), or you could use some Javascript to replace the text "(no title)" with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

teylyn is missing the point. I have sharepoint 2013.after i hit the spell check at the top of the add for the title entry totally went missing. It looks like a bug in the system. I have heard of editing the item after you add it but the issue is how to get the form back to its original appearance.